# How do I upgrade an end-of-life Ubuntu distribution?

Tags: ubuntu, upgrade

My `do-release-upgrade` fails. I get the following error message:

```
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Your Ubuntu release is not supported anymore.
For upgrade information, please visit:
http://www.ubuntu.com/releaseendoflife

Err Upgrade tool signature
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8c01::19 80]
Err Upgrade tool
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8c01::19 80]
Fetched 0 B in 0s (0 B/s)
WARNING:root:file 'raring.tar.gz.gpg' missing
Failed to fetch
Fetching the upgrade failed. There may be a network problem.
```

So it says my version is not supported anymore. I have Ubuntu Quantal (12.10). What should I do now?

Comment: It might not hurt to mention which version you currently have.  Also, do you have any network problems?

Comment: No, no networking problems. I've got Ubuntu quantal (12.10).

Comment: I have a system, which was installed with 13.04 and upgraded from that to 13.10 and later to 14.04. But I upgraded to 13.10 long before 14.04 was released, so things may have changed. It might be that upgrading directly from 13.04 to 14.04 is not supported, and it might be that upgrading to 13.10 is no longer supported. When upgrading from 12.04 to 14.04 I found that the `-p` parameter was required in order to perform the upgrade, though the error message I got was different.

Comment: @Kevin `raring` is 13.04. Are you trying to upgrade from 12.10 to 13.04? The supported releases are 12.04 and 14.04. I guess you want to upgrade to 14.04. If you would be going through 13.04 and 13.10 to get there it is going to take a while, it might be less work to do a fresh install of 14.04 instead of running through three upgrades. So the real question might actually be how to upgrade directly to 14.04 LTS. Which release does it chose, if you run `do-release-upgrade -p`?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! If I add the -p parameter, then I get exactly the same message:

Comment: root@vps8202:~# do-release-upgrade -p
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Your Ubuntu release is not supported anymore.
For upgrade information, please visit:
...

Err Upgrade tool signature                                                     
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1360:..::18 80]                               
Err Upgrade tool                                                               
  404  Not Found [IP: ...::18 80]                               
Fetched 0 B in 0s (0 B/s)                                                      
WARNING:root:file 'raring.ta

Answer (score 34):

I had this exact same issue and [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/91821/107952) solved the issue for me.

**In summary**:

The repositories for older releases that are not supported get moved to an archive server. There are repositories available at http://old-releases.ubuntu.com

So you have to rewrite your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file in order to use this server. Use the following `sed` command to do this:

```
sudo sed -i -e 's/archive.ubuntu.com\|security.ubuntu.com/old-releases.ubuntu.com/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Also comment out any entries in `sources.list` that point to `mx.*` servers

Now you are ready to do your update:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install update-manager-core
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

Comment: nope: `E: GPG error: http://us.old-releases.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease: Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NODATA' (does the network require authentication?)`

Comment: Your sed command didn't work for me because my existing URLs started with `us.`, I had to do `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list` and manually remove the `us.` part from all the URLs. After that I got some `Err:5 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy Release 404  Not Found [IP: ` and `Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default` errors/warnings, which was concerning. So I just gave up and spun up a new server with a newer OS from scratch and copied over my files...

Comment: An upgrade from 'groovy' to 'impish' is not supported with this tool. 
=== Command terminated with exit status 1 (Tue Apr  5 17:15:37 2022) ===

Comment: I got the same error as Michael. Just to try what happens, I ran `sudo do-release-upgrade --proposed`, and it seems to have worked. No clue what's different.

Answer (score 13):

You have to change all apt-sources from archive.ubuntu.com or security.ubuntu.com to "old-releases.ubuntu.com".

If you use the standard hostnames, as described above, you an replace this using:

```
sudo sed -i -e 's/archive.ubuntu.com\|security.ubuntu.com/old-releases.ubuntu.com/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

If you are using subdomains of mirrors in your country (e.g. "us.archive.ubuntu.com") use this command:

```
sudo sed -i -e 's/us.archive.ubuntu.com\|us.security.ubuntu.com/old-releases.ubuntu.com/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

old-releases.ubuntu.com doesn't support country-code-subdomains.

Answer (score 11):

Change all of your apt-sources to "old-releases.ubuntu.com". This `sed` command works with any/all ubuntu.com URLs and saves a backup copy in case you need to revert:

```
sudo sed -i.save -e 's/\/\/.*ubuntu.com/\/\/old-releases.ubuntu.com/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Upgrade all packages in your current (old and outdated) release and make sure you have the update manager installed:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install update-manager-core
```

Reboot:

```
sudo reboot
```

Upgrade to the latest release:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

Comment: Thanks, that allowed me to upgrade from 19.04 to 20.04 (via 19.10).

Comment: My old machine has 17.04 and this didn't do it.

Comment: Trying again after doing `s/zesty/artful/g` and seems to be making progress.

Comment: @Patrick what? how did you get it to work? zesty artful what?

Comment: @CQM I manually bumped the distribution it was looking for to the one dist-upgrade was supposed to use.

Comment: @Patrick I ended up adding a volume and copying my stored files, and connecting that volume to a new compute instance with new version of Ubuntu. Data center convenience. I don't consider that practical for everyone, but that's what I did!

Comment: This broke my sources.list.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit**: After some time, Ubuntu's `archive.ubuntu.com` repositories are moved to `old-releases.ubuntu.com`. This is what happened for the tar I linked. I updated the link. Moreover, it seems that the bug will be (or already is) resolved: see Ubuntu [Bug #1975533](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-release-upgrader/+bug/1975533)

---

I had similar problem. The only way of upgrading that worked in my case was:

```
wget http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/hirsute-updates/main/dist-upgrader-all/current/hirsute.tar.gz
tar -xvf hirsute.tar.gz
sudo ./hirsute
```

Details here: https://blog.invid.eu/2022/02/24/upgrade-eol-ubuntu-server-from-20-10-to-21-10-an-upgrade-from-groovy-to-impish-is-not-supported-with-this-tool-ubuntu-ubuntugeek-ubuntu-linux-eol-upgrade/

I wanted to upgrade from 20.10 to 22.04, but the intermediate step was to upgrade from 20.10 to 21.04. Nevertheless, the procedure should work for any past and future Ubuntu distribution.

---

Note! Before running the `UpgradeTool` I added the `old-releases.` to the domains/entries in the `/etc/apt/sources.list`. Operation similar to the one described in [randomcontrol's answer](https://serverfault.com/a/735590/611020):

```
sudo sed -i -e 's/archive.ubuntu.com\|security.ubuntu.com/old-releases.ubuntu.com/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

so that the:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

would work.

---

Additional information on that approach in the official documentation: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Comment: I got a 404 from the given wget url.

Comment: Hi, `archive.ubuntu.com` for this package has been changed to `old-releases.ubuntu.com`. I updated the link in my answer.

Comment: Thank for the update and the tip!

Comment: Worked for me and my 21.10 box, which I neglected a little bit. I initally planned to wait for the 22.04.1 release, however, I am too late for the party since support for 21.10 ended in July and 22.04.1 is planned for August (not yet released at the time of writing).

Comment: I’m glad it worked for you!

Answer (score 1):

None of these worked for me so I will share my own:

Replace all `"archive.ubuntu.com|security.ubuntu.com|ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/"` (including ubuntu-ports or not) to `old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/`

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem upgrading from Ubuntu 21.10 to latest. The solution to resolve the upgrading for Ubuntu 21.10, it's by following the step below:

Downloads the upgrader, check the link above for the URL of the file for your release

```
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/main/dist-upgrader-all/current/jammy.tar.gz
```

Extract it into a new directory

```
mkdir upgrader && tar -xaf jammy.tar.gz -C upgrader
cd upgrader
```

Run the executable, the name changes based on the release

```
./jammy
```

Answer (score -1):

Check this out https://butlerraines.com/code-stuff/upgrading-end-life-eol-ubuntu-version-ubuntu-1904

This is for Ubuntu 19.04 but should work for any distro.

Comment: Please don't post link only questions, they become useless when the link dies. Instead, post the essentials and link to the source for reference.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/516666)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).