# Having an error while upgrading Ubuntu 21.10 to 22.04

Tags: ubuntu, upgrade, ubuntu-22.04

Hi I am kinda new to Ubuntu. I am currently using Ubuntu 21.10 and trying to upgrade it to 22.04. When I enter

```
do-release-upgrade
```

It throws an error which is:

> Checking for a new Ubuntu release
> Your Ubuntu release is not supported anymore.
> For upgrade information, please visit:
> http://www.ubuntu.com/releaseendoflife
> Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading.

I have tried to install all the upgrades. Then I tried to upgrade by entering

```
sudo apt upgrade
```

Then I encountered this error below:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libtss2-esys-3.0.2-0 : Breaks: libtss2-esys0 (< 3.0.2-1) but 2.3.2-1 is to be installed
 libtss2-mu0 : Breaks: libtss2-esys0 (< 3.0.1-2) but 2.3.2-1 is to be installed
 libtss2-sys1 : Breaks: libtss2-esys0 (< 3.0.1-2) but 2.3.2-1 is to be installed
 libtss2-tcti-cmd0 : Breaks: libtss2-esys0 (< 3.0.1-2) but 2.3.2-1 is to be installed
 libtss2-tcti-device0 : Breaks: libtss2-esys0 (< 3.0.1-2) but 2.3.2-1 is to be installed
 libtss2-tcti-mssim0 : Breaks: libtss2-esys0 (< 3.0.1-2) but 2.3.2-1 is to be installed
 libtss2-tcti-swtpm0 : Breaks: libtss2-esys0 (< 3.0.1-2) but 2.3.2-1 is to be installed
E: Broken packages
```

I tried to update these package manually. Also tried to fix the E: Broken packages by using information from this website (https://www.makeuseof.com/how-to-find-and-fix-broken-packages-on-linux/) but it did not work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I upgrade an end-of-life Ubuntu distribution?](https://serverfault.com/questions/622735/how-do-i-upgrade-an-end-of-life-ubuntu-distribution)

Comment: For some reasons, whenever I try to use solutions from other postings, another error pops out. For example, due to permission issues, I cannot edit sources.list file. Somehow, I figured out that I can force to replace the sources.list file, it did not fix the problem... Also another issue popped up which is E: Broken packages by using information. I really do not know how to solve this problem. Should I just uninstall old version and install a new one?

Comment: It's impossible to say without seeing complete error messages and the configuration. For the future, you should stick to LTS releases to prevent such problems.

Answer (score 1):

Long story Short, I was able to upgrade my ubuntu from 21.10 to 22.04 LTS.

The most helpful website for me was

> https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

I followed instructions from the website step-by-step and was able to upgrade my ubuntu.

Thank you so much for you all's help and let me know if you all have any questions!